# Можно ли определить пользователя в триггере PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

Более подробно:
Есть база данных PostgreSql, запросы к которой могут выполняться одним из двух способов:

1. Из psql - в этом случае все просто, пользователь определяется параметром current_user
2. Из клиентского приложения, работающего с БД через браузер.
   Во втором случае коннект к базе выполняется от имени пользователя apache,
   т.е. и user тоже будет apache.
   Вопрос: можно ли как-то определить (в триггерах на таблицы) хотя бы IP клиентской машины пользователя, который выполнил текущий коннект?

Comment: [Системные информационные функции и операторы](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/functions-info)

Comment: По этой ссылке я вижу только одну функцию, которая похожа на то, что мне нужно, 
inet_client_addr () → inet

Выдаёт IP-адрес текущего клиента либо NULL, если текущее соединение установлено через Unix-сокет.

однако в моем случае, как и написано в документации, она выдает NULL

Comment: PostgreSQL в описанных случаях в принципе не может знать IP клиента - о нём знает Апач, но серверу он сию информацию сообщать не станет. Так что либо передавать в явной форме с Апачи сведения о пользователе, либо вместо абстрактного пользователя apache авторизоваться на Постгрессе с использованием переданных учётных данных. Кстати, а как вообще в такой схеме, с одной учёткой на всех, блюдётся безопасность и разделение доступа?

Comment: Нормально блюдется - через логин и пароль доступа к клиенту.
Наверное придется сделать обертку к стандартной ф-ии pg_connect, в которой передавать параметры пользователя и записывать в БД их связь с идентификатором процесса.
Можно так поступить?
Неудобно конечно - придется во всех приложениях, по которым нужно вести аудит, вносить это изменение, но если другого способа нет ...